# как использовать конструктор объекта из разных классов?

Tags: c#, классы, объекты, конструктор

Всем привет!

Такой вопрос если мне необходимо создать объект и передавать в него параметры из разных частей программы. Я ведь не могу каждый раз создавать экземпляр этого класса, ведь я получу разные объекты. Как это лучше сделать? 
Заранее спасибо за потраченное на меня время.

```
public class PrepareDataForDb  
{
    public string dID;
    public string dTimeGame;
    public string dCommandName1;

    public PrepareDataForDb(string TimeGame, string CommandName1)
    {
    }

    public PrepareDataForDb(string ID)
    {    
    }
}
```

====

```
public class GetInfo
{
    private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ID = tbGetID.Text;
        PrepareDataForDb prepareDataForDb = new PrepareDataForDb();
        prepareDataForDb(ID);
    }
}
```

====

```
public class GetInfo2
{
    private void bStart2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TimeGame = TimeGame.Text;
        string CommandName1 = CommandName1.Text;
        PrepareDataForDb prepareDataForDb = new PrepareDataForDb();
        prepareDataForDb(TimeGame, CommandName1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы говорите о глобальной переменной?

Comment: Не уверен. Я понимаю, что глобальная переменная доступна из любой точки программы. Вот мне надо конструировать один объект из нескольких классов. Мне не совсем удобно передавать каждый раз параметры между методами, чтобы в конце создать один раз экземпляр другого класса. Вообще как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Это должен быть всегда один и тот же объект? Или разные объекты одного типа?

Comment: Да один и тот же объект, но передавать в него параметры я буду из разных классов. Как в примере выше, я буду собирать объект из разных классов, с помощью конструктора. И когда все переменные будут переданы, я их использую все вместе, например добавалю в БД. Удобнее это сделать в одном классе, чем в остальных писать данные в БД по частям.

Comment: Передавайте этот объект параметром

Comment: Передавать его параметров в другой класс?

Comment: Окей, спасибо вам большое) разобрался